# Bundling not rendering styles

Tags: css, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I have a project where I am bundling files eg:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/master/supplierbundle").Include(
                      "~/Content/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css",
                      "~/css/mystyles.css"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

The files are bundled so in my page source I've got:

```
<link href="/css/master/supplierbundle" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

but the styles are not rendering - simply the page displays without any styling at all

It's not working in both debug or release mode.

**EDIT**

Within the head the bundles are inserted:

```
@Styles.Render("~/css/master/supplierbundle")
```

Comment: what do you get when you navigate to `/css/master/supplierbundle`?  Are there any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @Joseph `<html><body><h1>Page not found</h1><h3>No umbraco document matches the url '/css/master/supplierbundle'.</h3><p>This page can be replaced with a custom 404. Check the documentation for "custom 404".</p><p style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; padding-top: 10px"><small>This page is intentionally left ugly ;-)</small></p></body></html>`

Comment: That's your answer; the url in the href must be wrong.

Comment: Please share the code how the this link tag is added to your _layout/master page. I miss the cachebusting querystring, like in /content/master/supplierbundle?v=K8bEDKv6DE_2BHLRTdisqFsdq1BnRrJx3CvCQ_HR7eo1

Comment: It's not wrong, it's the bundle link @pfx

Comment: Looks like the url to the bundle '/css/bundle' gets intercepted by Umbraco and pointed to '/css/master/supplierbundle'.

Comment: No, the link everywhere is `/css/master/supplierbundle` including error source @pfx - I corrected the post

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the `~/bundles/` path is present in the umbracoReservedPaths key in the web.config file. If not Umbracco handles the url instead of ASP.NET's bundle-handler, which is happening as the 404 page returned mentions *'No **umbraco** document matches the url*.

There might be more paths in the value, but at least the `~/bundles/` must be present.

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/bundles/" />
```

Comment: No it's not this, I have the bundle path added to reserved paths @pfx

Comment: Did you try with the full path `~/css/master/supplierbundle`?

Comment: I tried the above and changed my bundles to be prefixed /bundles which is default and is also in umbraco reservedPaths. The problem still persists and it's very random, eg. I have 2 diffrent layouts that use different bundles and just random files from those bundles does not render in minification. I have no errors in the console either. Just some styling is not working @pfx